# How do I run ESLint from a saved Bash variable?

Tags: bash, variables, eslint, lint

I am setting up a project initialization script and a git pre-commit hook for work on a project. We have the scripts I want to run for linting not in the root directory but in a sub-directory and I would like to keep it that way.

What I want to be able to do is to set the full relative path to the binary executables for eslint and phpcs to bash variables then be able to run them. I also want to be able to execute the composer.phar binary from the bash variables.

So here is what I did.

```
# Set tool paths
PHPCS_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcs`
PHPCBF_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcbf`
ESLINT_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/eslint`
SASSLINT_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/sass-lint`
COMPOSER_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/composer.phar`
```

I was trying to test these paths locally from the project root directory and I keep getting errors.

I copy and paste one of those lines into my terminal, hit enter, then do one of the following:

- `${ESLINT_PATH}` and `command ${ESLINT_PATH}` and `"${ESLINT_PATH}"` and `$ESLINT_PATH` all yield me...

  ```
  zsh: command too long: eslint [options] file.js [file.js] [dir]\n\nBasic configuration...
  ```
- `eval "${ESLINT_PATH}"` and `eval $ESLINT_PATH` and `eval "$ESLINT_PATH"` all yield me...

  ```
  zsh: no matches found: [options]
  zsh: command not found: Basic
  zsh: command not found: --no-eslintrc
  zsh: command not found: -c,
  zsh: no matches found: [String]
  ```

Am I losing my mind? How in the world do I make the path executable? If I take the contents of the path and run it, it works just fine.

Example: `./wp-content/themes/swmaster/node_modules/.bin/eslint` actually tells me to specify a path.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you're using zsh or bash?

Comment: My local uses zsh, but I want this to be compatible with other devs machines.

Comment: We all use Mac OS X by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your issue is in these assignments:

```
# Set tool paths
PHPCS_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcs`
PHPCBF_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcbf`
ESLINT_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/eslint`
SASSLINT_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/sass-lint`
COMPOSER_PATH=`./wp-content/themes/our-theme/composer.phar`
```

Those back-ticks are command substitutions.  An easier to read way of writing this is would be:

```
PHPCS_PATH=$(./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcs)
...
```

I don't think that is what you really want.  A command substitution actually executes what is inside and is substituted by whatever goes to `stdout`.  I think you were actually trying to do string assignments.  This can be accomplished by simply removing the back-ticks because there are no spaces in the paths.  But it is a good habit to get into to just double quote them anyway.  Try this:

```
# Set tool paths
PHPCS_PATH="./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcs"
PHPCBF_PATH="./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcbf"
ESLINT_PATH="./wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/eslint"
SASSLINT_PATH="./wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/sass-lint"
COMPOSER_PATH="./wp-content/themes/our-theme/composer.phar"
```

Another method to solve your issue would be to add these directories to your `PATH` variable.  For example, if you set your `PATH` to include the bin directory for phpcs and phpcbf, you would be able to execute those programs without specifying a full (or relative in this situation) path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:./wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin
# or export PATH=$PATH:/full/path/to/wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin
# Now you can just run the line below without a path...
phpcs
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very informative. I went ahead and posted what I figured out this morning because it will work from any directory in the repo and works well.

Answer (score 0):

This morning I found what I was looking for in this gist: https://gist.github.com/rashtay/328da46a99a9d7c746636df1cf769675#file-pre-commit-eslint

**My solution is now:**

```
# Set tool paths
PHPCS="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcs"
PHPCBF="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wp-content/themes/our-theme/vendor/bin/phpcbf"
ESLINT="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/eslint"
SASSLINT="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/wp-content/themes/our-theme/node_modules/.bin/sass-lint"
```

This works from any directory in the repo because it ties to the repo base path. It is dynamic in that way.